# Does anyone know if there is any literature out there comparing mapjoins and reducejoins in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I need to compare the two for a presentation I'm preparing, but I cant use the data I've gathered on my own computer since that would be unreliable. If anyone has any literature on this it would be very helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can refer Chapter 8 of O'Reillys' Hadoop:The Definitive Guide book for Map and Reduce join.It has good comparision.